# google sheets: valores por defecto a valores filtrados por funcion query

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo una una lista de hojas que representan locales, cada local tiene equipos con sus datos (nombre, cantidad, detalles, fecha de ingreso, etc), en otra hoja se hace un seguimiento de las fechas de ingreso, para eso hice una query del tipo:

```
=query({LOC1!A1:G1;LOC2!A1:G1;LOC3!A1:G1;LOC4!A1:G1}, "SELECT Col1, Col7, Col8, Col10 WHERE Col10 is not null order by Col10 asc")
```

La columna 10 contiene la fecha y solo si se puso una fecha de ingreso se ve en el resultado.
Si bien esto funciona si la cantidad (columna 7) tiene campos vacios se supone que hay 1 equipo al menos y lo ideal seria que se autocomplete. Al no encontrar forma de hacerlo con el lenguaje de consulta de la formula query intente hacer un map de la siguiente forma:

```
=map(query({LOC1!A1:G1;LOC2!A1:G1;LOC3!A1:G1;LOC4!A1:G1}, "SELECT Col1, Col7, Col8, Col10 WHERE Col10 is not null order by Col10 asc label Col1 'equipo', Col7 'cantidad', Col8 'detalles', Col10 'fecha'"), lambda(cantidad,if(isblank(cantidad), 1, cantidad)))
```

El problema con esto es que tambien rellena con 1 las celdas vacias de los detalles.

¿Como podria completar con 1 solo las celdas de la columna cantidad?

Edit: el lenguaje de consulta de la funcion query no soporta la funcion IF ni CASE en la lista de seleccion.

Comment: Para completar con 1 solo las celdas de la columna cantidad, puedes usar la función IF en lugar de MAP. La fórmula sería algo asi:

=query({LOC1!A1:G1;LOC2!A1:G1;LOC3!A1:G1;LOC4!A1:G1}, "SELECT Col1, IF(Col7='', 1, Col7), Col8, Col10 WHERE Col10 is not null order by Col10 asc label Col1 'equipo', Col7 'cantidad', Col8 'detalles', Col10 'fecha'")

Comment: @pcandido de lo primero que intente pero la consulta falla al encontrar el caracter "(" leyendo la documentacion me encontre con que el lenguaje de consulta de la formula query no soporta la mayoria de las funciones standard ni tampoco la clausula CASE o subconsultas.

Comment: Y te podría valer calcular un campo nuevo en una nueva columna? Por ejemplo cantidadok e incluir una fórmula tipo: =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B2:B)=0, 1, B2:B)) ?

Comment: queria evitar eso porque la cantidad de hojas en realidad es bastante mayor a la que se ve en el ejemplo, al final la solucion que encontre fue hacer la consulta de la columna a la que queria aplicar el map por separado

Answer (score 1):

Encontre la forma de hacerlo al final, no es lo mas elegante pero funciona y se evita tener que agregar una columna nueva en cada hoja para el autocompletado (si bien aca el ejemplo lleva solo cuatro locales en la practica son unos sesenta y tantos). la solucion fue hacer 3 consultas una al lado de la otra, una para los equipos, otra para la cantidad la cual luego se pasa por una funcion map para autocompletar con 1 y otra que tiene todas las columnas que faltan.
quedaria asi:

```
//columna equipo
=query({LOC1!A1:G1;LOC2!A1:G1;LOC3!A1:G1;LOC4!A1:G1}, "SELECT Col1 WHERE Col10 is not null order by Col10 asc")

//columna cantidad (la que lleva el autocompletado)
=map(query({LOC1!A1:G1;LOC2!A1:G1;LOC3!A1:G1;LOC4!A1:G1}, "SELECT Col7 WHERE Col10 is not null order by Col10 asc"), lambda(cantidad,if(isblank(cantidad), 1, cantidad)))

//otras columnas
=query({LOC1!A1:G1;LOC2!A1:G1;LOC3!A1:G1;LOC4!A1:G1}, "SELECT Col8, Col10 WHERE Col10 is not null order by Col10 asc")
```

Espero le sirva a cualquiera que quiera hacer algo similar.